# Probability of adjacent cells of a grid have the same state.

Tags: probability

Information:

- There are ***x*** states
- States are equally probable
- Each cell can have only one state
- States in each cell is set independently
- The grid size is ***w*** (width) by ***h*** (height)

After setting the state of each cell, what is the probability that there is at least one path of length ***l*** for which all cells are in the same state? Only consider horizontal and vertical adjacency (diagonal adjacency is dis-considered).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The way the question is worded, it doesn't matter how the $l$ cells are related geometrically, You are being asked "given a path of $l$ cells, what is the probability that they are all in the same state ?"

Comment: Sorry, english is my second language.

Comment: @ww1 What I am trying to ask is: what are the chances of such path exist?

Comment: That is a much harder question. Are the $x$  states equally probable ?

Comment: @ww1 Yes they are. I edited the question with your observations.

Comment: how about "What is the probability that there is at least one path of length $l$ for which all cells are in the same state." - would that express what you want to know ?

Comment: @WW1 Definitely!

Comment: If $x=w=h=2$ then the probabilities you are looking for are...
$$ P(l=1)=\frac 2{16}   $$

$$ P(l=2)=\frac 4{16}   $$


$$ P(l=3)=\frac 8{16}   $$

 $$ P(l=4)=\frac 2{16}   $$

You want to find a formula for $P(l)$ in terms of $l,x,w,h$ , am I understanding you correctly ?